# should changes in node_modules invalidate the webpack build cache?

Tags: webpack

Webpack config [`cache.buildDependencies`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache/#cachebuilddependencies) can be used to list files or directories, such that if they change then the filesystem-based webpack build cache is invalidated.

This is documented in depth at the [persistent caching guide](https://github.com/webpack/changelog-v5/blob/master/guides/persistent-caching.md).

The doc says the webpack lib is included by default. Doc also shows how to include the `webpack.config.js` file itself.

Is it a stupid question to ask, how about `node_modules`?  They don't mention anything like `yarn.lock` either.  In some kinds of workspaces lib dependencies may appear in `node_modules` as symlinks - in those cases the dependency can be updated in parallel during development.  Those changes should invalidate these webpack build caches right?

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue with changes in packages linked with `npm link` not appearing even though both apps were rebuilt. Adding this to my webpack.config fixed it, but please don't ask me why exactly - docs are not super detailed on `snapshot`:

```
snapshot: {
        managedPaths: [/^(.+?[\\/]node_modules)[\\/]((?!your-modules)).*[\\/]*/],
    },
```

Comment: what is the regex trying to do? it seems it is saying that everything in node_modules apart from your-modules should be considered a managed path

Comment: My regex looks like this and it seems to work. I included my entire private namespace. `managedPaths: [/^node_modules\/(?!@ns).*/]`. And yes, this means, cache all `node_modules` except anything in `node_modules/@ns` directory.